# Oracle slow inserts

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle11g, sql-insert

In my system, there is an loading process that insert some data to some table.

(Oracle 11g)

The etl tool generate the command :

```
INSERT INTO TEMP (v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9)
    VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9);
```

(the fields are number and varchar2)

The loading is about 40K rows.

In the production the command take 25 minutes!

It's about 23 rows per second.

but when I'm trying to make the same load in the dev\test - it's realy fast.

This table has 1 index and it exist in the dev too.

The statistics of table\columns\index seems very similar in both prod and dev.

I even try to import the prod statistics into the dev, but no change..

any idea???

Thanks.

Comment: Bad tool.  Bad tool.  Learn about how to bulk load data into Oracle, such as through the SQL*Loader.

Comment: Maybe.. but the place i'm working in using it.. so I just can't replace it.

Comment: Has this post lost some comments? I added some yesterday that seem to have disappeared?

Comment: yes. now, I even can't see the answers that were here yesterday.. very strange.

Comment: @user2671057. Well, one thing I asked was, of the 25 mins, can you determine how much of that time is spent inserting the 40k rows? Even with an index on the table, 23 rows per second is woeful. I wonder if the ETL tool (which one are you using BTW), is doing some other processing between inserting each row?